# Missing files in HEC-RAS 5.0.3

Tags: save, hec-ras

I'm trying to create the files in HEC-RAS 5.0.3, but nothing is created. Even though the location of the project is shown in the main window, I can't find the file in this location. That causes this problem?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I only know that there is one thing which can alter the functionality of the program. Number separator, between integer and decimals, in PC setting must be the dot not the comma.